# why jekyll pagination not working locally?

Tags: github, pagination, jekyll, github-pages

I just start to use jekyll on github pages. My repository is https://github.com/yejinxin/yejinxin.github.io.

I build my local development in cygwin. It works pretty well util I try to get index posts paginated. I followed the [documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/), set paginate: 5 in my _config.yml, and got 404 errors on `http://localhost:4000/pageN`. And I can't find _site/page2/ folder or _site/page3/ folder, but there is a _site/page/ folder!

I have no idea what's going wrong. I tried `jekyll serve --watch --trace`,`jekyll serve`, restart server, and so on, but no good. However, after I pushed my commits to github, It works on github! So, it seems like it's my local environment problem.

I'm new to jekyll and ruby, don't know how to debug this. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, seems like it's a just known bug. https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/pull/1063